# window.frame.document.location.href is pointing differently in IE11

Tags: javascript, html

On my web page I have multiple frames out of which one frame has following location: /lms/index_lms.html

Now, I want to load present.html file in that frame which is at location: /present.html

I am currently using `window.my-frame-id.document.location.href = 'present.html';`

This works in IE9, IE10, Chrome and FF but doesn't work in IE11.
In IE11 it tries to search present.html file with following path: /lms/present.html

I can't use `document.location.href='/present.html'` because, I have few other folder/directories on my webserver before lms folder.

Since this issue happens in IE11 only can any one help me in identifying why this happens. Also, what is the correct way to set present.html page to that frame.

Comment: `../../present.html` perhaps?

Comment: `window.frames.document.location.href` is not supposed to refer anything in any browser. Please elaborate your code.

Comment: Yeah, You are right. `window.frames["nameOfiFrame"].document.location.href` is better or [0] for the first frame

Comment: Apart from `frames` collection, you can also get a reference to the `(i)frame` element, and set its `src`.

Comment: @mplungjan - You are right, I'm using frame-id but I kept "frames" instead of id in this post :-). Also, "../present.html" works in IE11 but then it doesn't work in IE9-10, Chrome. So can't go with it. The target frame already loading a file from "lms" folder and that's why IE11 loads the page from lms folder. I wonder how it works perfectly in other browsers.

Comment: @Teemu - You are right, I'm using frame-id but I kept "frames" instead of id in this post :-)